# AutoCAD Dynamo Python Scipt - Edit Table Cell Information

Tags: python, autocad

Can I get some help writing my first Autocad/Civil 3d Dynamo Python Script. I am trying to edit table cell information but need a push in the right direction. An example of a table cell attribute I would want to edit is the table cell scale. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my post on the dynamo forums that goes into better details:
https://forum.dynamobim.com/t/python-civil-3d-table-edit-table-cell-information/97785

I tried using dynamo nodes to complete the task but I couldn't find any so I am going to try to use the python node.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.